How to download available version of Mongo Client from repository
I am using flapdoodle for my integration junit. In this junit I am downloading MongoDb binaries and starting the mongo db


Mongod mongod = distributionBaseUrl() -> {
 return Start.to(DistributionBaseUrl.class).initializedWith(
   DistributionBaseUrl.of("https://artifactrepository/ ..../mongo") 
 )
};

TransitionWalker.ReachedState<RunningMongoProcess> run = mongod.start(Version.withFeatures(ImmutableGenericVersion.of(5.6.9)))



Above line trying to download the these binaries "http://artifactrepository/ ..../mongo/linux/mongod-linux-x86_64-rhel80-5.6.9.tgz"
But available binaries are  "http://artifactrepository/ ..../mongo/linux/mongod-linux-x86_64-rhel70-5.6.9.tgz"
so only difference is of rhel version
How can download available binaries?

Are you using a Maven or Gradle?  Are you using Spring?  If you are using Spring and one of Maven/Gradle you won't need to get involved with retrieving binaries like that - it is all automatic.
